# @Path with regexp not working as advertised

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I'm trying to build an endpoint in my REST API (I'm using Resteasy 3.0.2) that answers on either /catalog/foo/dump or just /catalog/dump.  According to the Resteasy docs, this should work:

```
@Path("/catalog)
public class MyResource {

   @GET
   @Path("{var:.*}/dump")
   public String dump() {...}
}
```

You can see this example in the manual at: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/userguide/html/Using_Path.html

I'm not seeing the expected behavior, though.  Only /catalog/(something)/dump responds as expected.  /catalog/dump throws the following:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotAllowedException: No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:370)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:113)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:444)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:234)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:171)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to debug in SegmentNode.java to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I would make 2 methods:

```
@GET
@Path("/dump")
public String dump1() {
  return dump("");
}

@GET
@Path("/{var:.*}/dump")
public String dump2(@PathParam("var") String var) {
  dump(var);
}
```